# Complexity of recursion T(n) = 2T(n-1) + C?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to calculate the Time Complexity of the Recursive Function, suppose this,

```
function T(int n){
 if(n == 1) return 1;
 return T(n-1) + T(n-1);
}
```

the time complexity equation is: `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + C`, taking `C = 1 and T(1) = 1`.
Now, since I am working on this, I am confused whether I am doing the right process using `Back Substitution`. This is how I approached the calculation.
I have followed the below question, but did not find it very satisfactory, so raising the question again.

- [Complexity of Recursion T(n) Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714365/complexity-of-the-recursion-tn-tn-1-tn-2-c)

This is how I approached the problem:

```
1. T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1
2. T(n-1) = 2T(n-2) + 1 //since we have T(n-1) in Eq(1)
3. T(n-2) = 2T(n-3) + 1 //since we have T(n-2) in Eq(2)
```

**Back Substitution to Solve for final complexity**

```
1. T(n-1) = 2(2T(n-3) + 1) + 1
2. T(n) = 2(2(2T(n-3) + 1) + 1) + 1
        = 2(4T(n-3) + 1 + 2) + 1
        = 8T(n-3) + 1 + 6
        = 8T(n-3) + 7
        = 8T(n-3) // Ignoring 7, since it is a constant
        = 2^3T(n-3)
        = 2^kT(n-k)
```

**Substituting the value of K, since base case is n = 1**

```
1. n-k = 1
2. k = n-1

//Substituting the value of k in the above T(n) Equation
T(n) = 2^{n-1}T(n-n+1)
     = 2^{n-1}T(1)
     = 2^{n-1} * 1
     = 2^{n-1}
```

So from above I got 2<sup>n-1</sup>, is the above process correct, or needs improvement. I am starting off with time complexity, and this recursion is kind of tricky for me. Please help!

Comment: Increasing `n` by 1 doubles the runtime, so intuitively, you should expect exponential runtime, just as your calculation shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact equation is (if $T(1) = 1$):

$$ T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1 = 2(2T(n-2) + 1) + 1 = $$
$$ 2^2 T(n-2) + 2 + 1 = $$
$$ 2^2(2T(n-3) + 1) + 2 +‌ 1 = 2^3 T(n-3) + 2^2 + 2 + 1$$

Hence, $T(n) = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \cdots + 1 = 2^n - 1$ (by mathematical induction).

Comment: I really appreciate that, how easily you broke it into a simpler series, having the equation `8T(n-3) + 7` differs the solution, however, the end equation was same only, that is, `8T(n-3) + 7 = 2^3T(n-3) + 2^2 + 2^1 + 1`. Thanks @OmG, I need to learn this thing of identifying the pattern. Just a quick question, what is the problem of solving the same with my approach, could you please throw some light on it?

Comment: @Alok my pleasure. You can prove that by the mathematical induction. Easy here.

Comment: Hey @OmG, I am not very good at mathematical induction, could you please share a link so that I can read more about it. Pardon me for my mathematics, but I am willing to learn about since, This is something important which I need to know now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For a shortcut to the exact expression, add `C` on both sides of the recurrence and write it as:

```
    T(n) + C = 2 (T(n-1) + C)
```

Define `U(n) = T(n) + C` then the above gives `U(n) = 2 U(n-1)`.

Therefore `U(n)` is a geometric progression with common ratio `2`, so `U(n) = 2^n U(0)`, then:

```
    T(n) = U(n) - C
         = 2^n U(0) - C
         = 2^n (T(0) + C) - C
```

For `C = 1` and `T(0) = 0` this reduces to `T(n) = 2^n - 1`.

Comment: Hey @dxiv, could you please explain how did this equation become `2^n U(0)`, according to the Geometric Progression. As far as my knowledge is concerned, GP = `ar^{n-1}`, where `r` is the `common ratio`. Taking 2 as your common ratio, then how did you proceed to get `2^n U(0)`?

Comment: @Alok It's the same thing. Using your formula `U(n) = U(1) 2^(n-1)`. But if you consider the progression to start at `n=0` then `U(1) = 2 U(0)` so `U(n) = 2 U(0) 2^(n-1) = 2^n U(0)`.